# How to group radio buttons from two different horizontal button box

Tags: c, radio-button, glade, gtk2

I am *C programming* a GUI, designed using the *Glade Interface Designer* with *Gtk2*. I can't select or deselect my **Radiobuttons** as all are active everytime. The below shown window have 6 radiobuttons in two different horizontal buttons box. How to make desired radio button selected??? 
I want to make only one active at a time. Help!

[image: This is My Glade window, where you can see the radio buttons.]

The above radio buttons is to be grouped from different button box.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Deep Jyoti Gharphalia,

Are u sure that u made a Buttongroup and added all the buttons into it?

For checking you could use LINQ:

```
var checkedButton = container.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
```

Note that this requires that all of the radio buttons be directly in the same container (eg, Panel or Form), and that there is only one group in the container. If that is not the case, you could make Lists in your constructor for each group, then write list.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked).

Zhunder

Comment: No, I didn't make a group...how to create and add them actually when I am using it on my own GUI window! I did a lot of search but didn't get anything like you know.

Comment: Put all radio buttons for a group in a container object like a Panel or a GroupBox. That will automatically group them together in Forms.

Comment: Yes, but Sorry I can't get those codes format for Gtk2....this is what the problem is. After all searches I made I got this idea already to group them.but how??

Comment: and @Zhunder LINQ cant be used in C language I think so far as I know.

Comment: oh yeah its actually for C# and C++ , sorry was my fault

Comment: :) yes! I am unable to do grouping an all...can u help me out looking at the image I have given?? and its ok...

Comment: i rly dont know how to work with the gtk2 interface designer, that was my only advice, because in most languages it this problem people have, maybe google it...